# namespaces not being autoloaded by composer update

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have external repository written in vanilla PHP which I want to use in my Symfony project the 'composer require' call works fine and all the files are loaded into the vendor directory. At run time I keep getting the following error.

```
Attempted to load class "FM" from namespace "MyRepo1\Src\Vendors\FM".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I thing it may be the composer.json of the PHP repository, included below.

```
{
    "name" : "myUserName/MyRepo1",
    "minimum-stability" : "dev",
    "repositories" : [{
            "type" : "git",
            "url" : "https://github.com/myUserName/MyRepo2"
        }
    ],
    "require" : {
        "myUserName/MyRepo2" : "*",
        "php" : "^7.0"
    },
    "version" : "1.0.2",
    "require-dev" : {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "5.5.*",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer" : "2.*",
        "mayflower/php-codebrowser" : "~1.1"
    }
}
```

below is the FM class which is in the directory vendor/myUserName/MyRepo1/src/vendors tracking.interface and tracking.class are in the same directory

```
<?php
namespace MyRepo1\Src\Vendors\FM;
// : Includes
include_once (dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .    'tracking.interface');
include_once (dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tracking.class');
// : End
use MyRepo1\Src\Vendors\Vendors as Vendors;
use MyRepo1\Src\Vendors\TrackingInterface as TrackingInterface;

class FM extends Vendors\Vendors implements TrackingInterface\TrackingInterface
{

}
```

Are there any changes that I need to make to the composer.json file so that the classes will be autoloaded correctly with a `composer update`.

Comment: Welcome back Sarah.  I see you are still struggling with this.  I would suggest modifying the applications's composer.json file per you previous question.  Once you get that working then look at the composer.json file for other components to see how they do it.

Comment: thanks @Cerad I've tried all the suggestions that you gave me making sure that there weren't any typos and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Unless it is some kind of private secret, please post the actual composer command you used to install the actual repo.  I'm willing to take a look.  Otherwise, all I can suggest is reviewing: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Looks like it is private.  Or at least I can't load it.  This really should not be difficult.  Might consider starting a fresh project, installing just the library and then trying to get a simple new FM() to work in the default controller.  It is possible that you may have inadvertently changed something else.

Comment: thanks @Cerad i'll try that. I'm going to delete my previous comment for security sake. One of my colleagues is also working on a few changes that might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

we eventually solved this by adding

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Vendors\\" : "src/"
    }
},
```

to the composer.json and changed the namespace of the classes to `namespace Vendors;` so that it would be the same as the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way your namespace is written your file should be located in

```
MyRepo1\Src\Vendors\FM\FM.php;
```

Comment: I've tried this but it still isn't working. I also made sure that I cleared the cache and ran `composer dump-autoload`